# CXF web service ClassCastException on assignment of return type when using WS-Reliable Messaging

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf, ws-reliablemessaging

I have a WSDL-first web service that is using CXF 2.7.6, using Wrapped-style. The getState web service interface method returns an int value. However, when I call the web service from my CXF client code, I usually get a ClassCastException with the message 'can't cast a GetStateResponse object to an Integer'. I say usually because the ClassCastException does not occur every time I make the web service call. I also intermittently get a similar ClassCastException on calls to other methods in the web service interface. Interestingly, this exception only occurs with WS-Reliable Messaging configured. We are deploying on a JBoss EAP 6 server but are using the CXF libraries directly (rather than using JBoss' built-in webservices subsystem)

I'm able to work-around the issue by assigning the return value to an Object and then determining its type and handling it accordingly, but this is a definite hack and I'd like to find the root cause of the issue. Below are excerpts from the WSDL, schema and interface class.

WSDL excerpts:

```
<wsdl:definitions>
    <wsdl:message name="getState">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="msgs:getState"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType>
        <wsdl:operation name="getState">
            <wsdl:input name="getState" message="tns:getState"/>
            <wsdl:output name="getStateResponse" message="tns:getStateResponse"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="SOAPFaultException" message="tns:SOAPFaultException"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding>
        <wsdl:operation name="getState">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="getState">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="getStateResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="SOAPFaultException">
                <soap:fault name="SOAPFaultException" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

SCHEMA referenced with 'msgs:' prefix above:

```
<xs:element name="getState" type="tns:getState"/>

<xs:complexType name="getState">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="param1" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="param2" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

INTERFACE CLASS:

```
@WebResult(name = "return", targetNamespace = "")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "getState", targetNamespace = "http://messages.space.my.name", className = "my.name.space.GetState")
@WebMethod
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "getStateResponse", targetNamespace = "http://messages.space.my.name", className = "my.name.space.GetStateResponse")
public int getState(
@WebParam(name = "param1", targetNamespace = "")
java.lang.String param1,
@WebParam(name = "param2", targetNamespace = "")
java.lang.String param2) throws SOAPFaultException;
```

Spring jaxws client configuration:

```
<jaxws:client id="wsProxy" serviceClass="my.name.space.IWebServiceInterface">
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <bean id="loggingInInterceptor" 
              class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" >
            <property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
        </bean>
        <ref bean="rmLogicalIn"/>
        <ref bean="rmCodec"/>
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
    <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <bean id="loggingOutInterceptor" 
              class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" >
            <property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
        </bean>
        <ref bean="rmLogicalOut"/>
        <ref bean="rmCodec"/>
    </jaxws:outInterceptors>
</jaxws:client>
```

Stack trace:

```
[33m [0m [31m00:39:20,589 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/TEST_GUI].[jsp]] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:8009-9) JBWEB000236: 
Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: my.name.space.messages.GetStateResponse cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer [0m
[31m    at $Proxy139.getState(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.jsp.client.framework.MWS_005fTEST_jsp.waitForState(MWS_005fTEST_jsp.java:166) [0m
[31m    at org.apache.jsp.client.framework.MWS_005fTEST_jsp._jspService(MWS_005fTEST_jsp.java:508) [0m
[31m    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:365) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at mil.jpmis.cbrnis.client.framework.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:148) [TESTGUI.jar:] [0m
[31m    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:91) [0m
[31m    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:72) [0m
[31m    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:512) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-2] [0m
[31m    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:490) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:420) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.4.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.4.10.Final-redhat-1] [0m
[31m    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
```

I also posted this on the cxf-users Nabble list, but no response yet.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you generating the jax-ws clients, if u are using cxf wsdl2java can you please tell which version

Comment: Thank you for your reply Ashok.  We are currently using wsdlToJava version 2.7.4 to generate client code.  In our Java client code we were using (1) `Service.create` and then `service.getClient` to get the client proxy, then switched to using (2) a jaxws:client bean in our Spring configuration file (I just added this to my original post above), with our Java client code using `context.getBean("wsProxy")` and `ClientProxy.getClient(...)` to get the client proxy.  In both cases we are intermittently getting the same error.

Comment: I should add that we've determined that my workaround of assigning the return value from the web service call to an Object in our Java client code does not seem to work, we still get the intermittent ClassCastException attempting to cast GetStateResponse to an Integer type, so it seems like the ClassCastException is occuring in the CXF or JAXWS code in the proxy.

Comment: @mks Was there any solutions for this? I'm facing the same issue right now.

Answer (score 0):

Update, and to respond to @gnzlrm in the comment above, if I recall correctly (this was over 2 years ago) we never did isolate the cause of this issue, but we did find when we updated to a later version of CXF we no longer saw the issue (I believe 2.7.13 and up worked but we ended up updating to 3.1.7).